# Pandas error: isin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code, which includes a list with varing capitalisation. I would like to set the Pandas code to ignore case sensitivity, using case = False, however my code is triggering the following error:

TypeError: isin() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case'

```
import pandas as pd

simple_upstream_types = ("Single rate",
                             "Single rate 2",
                            )


raw_df_simple = raw_df.loc[raw_df['upstream_rate_type'].isin([simple_upstream_types], case=False)]
```

Can you please assist

Comment: `isin` doesn't take a `case` argument at all...

Comment: check documentation for [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.contains`, which does accept flags, along with converting `simple_upstream_types` to a regex:

```
import re

raw_df_simple = raw_df[raw_df['upstream_rate_type'].str.contains('|'.join(simple_upstream_types), flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up formatting the pandas column to lowercase entries, which worked well against my lowercase list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. using `numpy` `where`, create a new column that compares the types list and the column values (in lower cases). Then a new column to say if it `matches` or `unmatched`. see a mockup below:

```
import pandas 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'UpstreamTypes': ["single rate","Single ratE","Single Rate","Single rate 2"]})
simple_upstream_types = ["Single rate","Single rate 2"]
df['Status'] = np.where(df.UpstreamTypes.str.lower().isin([v.lower() for v in list_of_values]),'Matched', 'Unmatched')
df
```

Result below:

```
UpstreamTypes   Status
0   single rate Matched
1   Single ratE Matched
2   Single Rate Matched
3   Single rate 2   Matched
```